failing to return response using nextApiResponse
I've been trying to send a response on Nextjs but it I get this error on Vercel

inside catch 1 TypeError: t.status is not a function

my code:
export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res : NextApiResponse){

   return res.status(200).send(3);
}

I've tried to send it as json using NextResponse and it works all good. but I need to send data this way.

i believe you are using app router

yes i'm using this in app/api @cmgchess

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) { const response = new NextResponse('3', {status: 200}); return response; } something like this?

cool if u want u can put as answer

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) { 
const response = new NextResponse('3', {status: 200}); return response; 
}


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
